# SimpleTable - шаблонный класс для создания таблиц в консоли

Tags: c++, github, консоль, table, проект

Я тут сделал небольшой проект на С++, и хотел поделиться с вами, вдруг вам понадобится создавать таблицу в консоли.

Что может мой шаблонный класс:
Шаблон для создания, хранения вывода таблицы в консоли. Можно добавлять колонки, удалять. Добавлять элементы в колонки, удалять. Показывать все таблицу, только нужную строку, только нужный столбец, только нужный элемент. Также можно получить доступ к элементам по отдельности.
[Ссылка на github](https://github.com/Starikov32/SimpleTable)

Если есть предложения по улучшению или советы, с радостью приму!

Comment: это такой метод самопиара или же нужно код ревьювить ваш?

Comment: скриншот в bmp почти 2мб длинной? png - нет не слышали. Конструкторы, которые получают "std::string * columnNames" ...

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, Я бы хотел поделиться своим кодом, чтобы другие не делали то что уже есть. А также ревью мне не помешает

Comment: @KoVadim А что не так с std::string в конструкторе?

Comment: там явно нужно использовать `const std::vector<std::string>&`. И не нужно будет передавать указатель + размер. Это даже работать скорее всего будет быстрее. И такого по всему коду очень много

Comment: @KoVadim, ок, поправлю, Спасибо!